# How do I find the sum of prime factors of $(1750 + 1225)^{1229}$?

Tags: prime-factorization

The number is: $(1750 + 1225)^{1229}$

My professor did this example in class, but I didn't really understand this. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: The prime factors are 1229 repetitions of the prime factors of the base (1750+1225) = 2975.  So start by factoring that into primes.

Comment: Also, it's unclear whether you want just a sum of distinct prime factors, or a sum with prime factors added according to multiplicity.

Comment: Figured it out!
factored each side of the statement (1750 and 1225).
then I factored each side added up (so factor(factor + factor))
then I just had (5^2*7(17))^1229
5^2258*7^1129*17*1129 = M

5+7+17 = 29.

Comment: @bert, is there a typo in the problem statement?  In your comment you are using $1129$ and $2258 = 2 \cdot 1129$, but the question has $1229$ - not that it changes the principles though.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming, given the lack of clarity, that you need to find the sum of distinct prime factors (disregarding multiplicity of any given prime factor), find the prime factors of the sum $$1750 + 1225 = 2975$$

$$(1750 + 1225)^{1229} = (2975)^{1229}  = (5^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 17)^{1229}= \left(5^2\right)^{1229}\cdot (7)^{1229}\cdot (17)^{1229}$$

Now you need to determine whether you need to

- sum $2\cdot 1229$ factors of 5, and $1229$ factors of $7$, and $1229$ factors of $17$
- or simply sum the distinct prime factors $5$ and $7$ and $17$: In the latter
  case, your sum will be $5 + 7 + 17 = 29$.

Either way, you'll have your result.

Comment: I think you have an arithmetic error. $5^3 \cdot 41$ is $5125$; $2975$ is $5^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 17$.

Comment: Corrected, @half-integerfan. Thanks: I transposed incorrectly from the scratch paper I had written on.